# c# how to make symbols stay turned on console (memory game)

Tags: c#

I'm stuck at a part where I want my symbols to stay flipped if they match. It's a simple 4x4 memory game for a project. Should I make a new method? It would be nice if someone could tell me if I can somehow reset the board by pressing a key.

I'm a total beginner so if someone could explain this in a really easy way to me, that would help me a lot. Currently i'm stuck on this.

```
using System;

namespace Memory
{
    class Program
    {

        static Coordinate[,] board = new Coordinate[4, 4];

        static int PosX = 0;
        static int PosY = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //randomize

            char[] symbols = new char[] { '#', '#', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C' };
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int y = 0; y < board.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < board.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    Coordinate c = new Coordinate();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        int index = rnd.Next(symbols.Length);
                        if (symbols[index] != ' ')
                        {
                            c.Symbol = symbols[index];
                            symbols[index] = ' ';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    board[y, x] = c;
                }
            }

            while (true)
            {
                DrawBoard();

                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                if(key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                {
                    PosX--;
                }
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    PosX++;
                }
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    PosY--;
                }
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                {
                    PosY++;
                }
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                {
                    board[PosY, PosX].IsOpen = true;
                }

                Console.Clear();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DrawBoard()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < board.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < board.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    if(x == PosX && y == PosY)
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    }
                    if (!board[y, x].IsOpen)
                    {
                        Console.Write(". ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(board[y, x].Symbol + " ");
                    }
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class Coordinate
    {
        public char Symbol;
        public bool IsOpen;
        public bool isDone;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the line:

```
board[PosY, PosX].IsOpen = true;
```

to

```
board[PosY, PosX].IsOpen = !board[PosY, PosX].IsOpen;
```

The chosen field will flip back, when it is chosen again.

Or to flip the complete board back with the letter "R":

```
if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.R)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < board.GetLength(0); y++)
   {
      for (int x = 0; x < board.GetLength(1); x++)
      {
         if (board[y, x].IsOpen) board[y, x].IsOpen = false;
      }
   }
}
```

You should extend this if `isDone` is implemented, because if a field `isDone` it should probably not be reverted back?

Comment: Thank you Luuk for the help!

What I meant was, when I open two of the fields, if they're not matching then both of them flip back automatically. For example if I open "#" and "a" then it should close because they aren't matching. Also I want them to stay open when they do match.

Comment: When you wrote that code yourself, you should be smart enough to do that. HINT: when setting isOpen to True, you could also increment a counter, and when it reached the value of 2, compare the two open fields, close them if they are not equal, do something else if they are equal.

Comment: This code is partially done by me, mostly done by the teacher who is teaching me c#. 

I've tried to do what you said for since you sent your comment, but I have no idea how to do it still. Might need some assistance. What do you mean by counter? Should I do it in the Main method or in a whole new method, if so how would it look like? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to say, but your teacher skipped a (basic) part of the lesson in programming.

Comment: Nooo, he didn't. I'm just really overwhelmed and I don't learn quickly. I have an exam in 2 days about explaining this and I'm really clueless about what to do. Also english isn't my native language so I don't understand some things in english.

Comment: Ohh you meant counter as in counting stuff hahaha. Sorry about that. I thought you meant a code countering another code or something like that. My bad